# my jsp page never loads

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have a J2EE web application, that runs on a shared Tomcat on a server.
Sometimes the website never loads, takes almost 5-10 minutes! It never loads or show any error during that time, and after trying many times, it finally shows the error: `(111) connection refused`.
I dont know what the cause is. Can anyone tell me what the problem could be? Is it my application or the hosting company ?
By the way the website keeps working for 1,2 days and then the above scenario happens.

The application is JSP and uses Hibernate to connect to a MySQL database.

Comment: Generated a stack trace?

Comment: see log files. What error you find there?

Comment: @dave: the ip and port are correct?

Comment: @harry : yes, everything is correct, the application runs normally for 1 or 2 days, then out of no where this happens. then it shows mt (111) connection refused error and a bit after that it shows : Service Temporarily Unavailable

Comment: Do you have the possibility to connect with a debugger and see where it hangs?

Comment: Actually I meant can you FORCE a dump?

Comment: Good tip from MJB, do you have the possibility to run the 'jstack' command and generate a thread dump?

Comment: no i cant do it on a shared server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally find the problem :

```
public class HibernateUtil {
  private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

  private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
      // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
      return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
      // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
      System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
      throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
  }

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
  }
}
```

as you can see above the `getSessionFactory()` method always leads to `buildSessionFactory()` so every time that i called `hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()` any where in my code, hibernate has made more and more connections to database and it made database non responsive :)

Answer (score 1):

Try running the [jstack](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html) command on the server when as soon as it hangs. The command will create a very helpful thread dump of your running (or blocked) threads and you can figure out what is causing the trouble.

Comment: Awkward to do with a shared container.

Comment: Jep... but you can afterwards search for your package name(s) in the stack traces and find the important ones. Connecting with a debugger will probably not be possible on a shared container.

Comment: Also, the instrumentation can change what is observed; that's particularly likely with this sort of problem, alas.

Comment: thnx but i dont think that i can use that command on a shared server, because no ssh or any kind o scripting is allowed

Answer (score 1):

I've observed something very much like this with my deployment server, and not yet had the opportunity to chase it down properly (that server only has the JRE installed, not the full JDK, and it's heavily firewalled too). From watching the logs, I know that it is apparently just hanging during the initialization stage of the (principal) webapp, and nothing else is happening during that time (from watching system logs; the whole system is quiescent at the time, with no processes being runnable) and I know that it only seems to happen when booting the whole container, and *not* when installing the webapp into an already-running container.

That leads me to speculate that the problem is due to some kind of unpleasant interaction between the Java runtime and the intensive class loading going on inside the webapp. For example, if there's JIT data that's getting flushed by the GC from a weak hash map before it's really finished with, that could push everything into some slower path through the code with (many) more wait states. (I've hunted such things in the past; they're *very* hard to track down because everything is still behaving correctly, if non-optimally, and it could well be a problem across many levels of an application.)

My best advice is to

1. be careful about boot order (e.g., make sure that the DB is up and stable before bringing up Tomcat)
2. don't use dynamic/lazy loading of webapps (it destroys reproducibility)
3. *be patient*: don't try to access the webapp until it indicates that it is ready (if you can, lock out connections to the Tomcat instance until it has brought up all the webapps inside it).